# Handle big hash tables in C++

Tags: c++, hash-function

Im writing a program where i got a lot of Data which is stored as blocks (4096 byte). For each block (if hash value not already exists) i create an Hashtable(std::multimap) entry. An Entry looks like this

Key: hashvalue SHA256 -> 64 bytes

Value: RefLink

```
struct RefLink{
    uint32_t rCounter; //4 bytes
    uint64_t blockposition; // 8 bytes
};
```

So every Entry takes a total of 76 bytes. If I have a 100 gb of data blocks my Hashtable will be about 1.85 gb big. And if I have 8 Terabytes of Data .... you know where this is going. Do you have any tips how i could solve this. Is there another way I don't see to manage my Hashtable. Is there a better Hashfunction (which already implemented in C++) that could save some more memory and don't have any collision? Or maybe can I compress the table-entrys in some way while the program is running?

Comment: At 8 terabytes, you're looking for a database, not a hashmap

Comment: Also note that `std::multimap` is not a hash table.

Comment: If your blocksize is 4096, a 32-bit unsigned `blockposition` can address ~17.5 terabytes worth of blocks. You might not need the blockposition to be 64-bit.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili im using the multimap as a "Hashtable" because it contains my hashvalues. But maybe this is the wrong word for this because it contains more then just the hashvalues.

Comment: @JackChaker see [std::unordered_multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)

Comment: Are you running on a computer with 100GB of RAM?  If not, trying to store 100GB of data in a `std::multimap` (or any in-memory container, for that matter) is not going to work very well :).

Comment: Your question doesn't give a clear indication of what you're trying to do.  You say you want SHA256 hash values to be your keys (they're 32 bytes each BTW), which means the multimap will store ordered SHA256s, and you'll only be able to do operations on the table by either knowing a SHA256 value (from an earlier hash, or by hashing another 4k block), or by brute-force searching the entire data.  You won't be able to do efficient lookups by blockposition or rCounter.  Is that really useful for something?

Comment: @JackChaker `std::multimap` is an associative [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that keeps the data in a **sorted** data structure (red-black tree for example). It's not hash-based. If you actually want a hashed container you want the `std::unordered_foo` containers.

Comment: with "hashtable" I mean it is my list of hashvalues. not the std::multimap itself. @TonyDelroy if a new block comes I will check its hashvalue. if hashvalue already exists I would not put the block into the system. if not this block will be saved. It is a deduplication tool.

Comment: @TonyDelroy it is 64 byte Ascii representation of the hashvalue. But i should put this into an 32 bytes bit representation....

Comment: @EOF you are right thx Im using the stream.seekg(), seekp() etc. they take a long as paramater. Anyway the 4 bytes wouldn't make that much difference.

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 should have good avalanche properties ( changing 1 bit in the plain text should have a 50% chance of changing every bit in the hash)

It should therefore be safe to only use part of the sha256 hash as your hash. Obviously the fewer bits you include the higher the probability of a collision.

Comment: Thx. But this sound a little bit to critical for me. I actually made a mistake by saving the sha256 as a 64 bytes Ascii character. I reduced it to 32 bytes now.

Answer (score 0):

> if hashvalue already exists I would not put the block into the system. if not this block will be saved. It is a deduplication tool.

I recommend creating an actual hash table keyed on the SHA256 key, with each bucket containing a fixed-length array of SHA256 values that have collided there, and a same-length array of your RefLink objects.  Very roughly, off the top of my head:

```
using sha256 = std::array<std::byte, 32>;
constexpr size_t max_slots = 16;
struct Bucket {
    std::vector<sha256> shas_;
    std::vector<RefLink> reflinks_;
};
std::vector<Bucket> buckets_;

void insert(const Data& data) {
    sha256 shaA = calc_sha256(data);

    size_t bucket_index_A = mod(sha256A, buckets_.size());
    auto& bucket_A = buckets_[bucket_index_A];

    sha256 shaB = shaA;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; ++i)
    std::swap(shaB[i], shaB[31-i]);  // cheap second hash value
    size_t bucket_index_B = mod(sha256B, buckets_.size());
    auto& bucket_B = buckets_[bucket_index_B];
    
    for (auto& bucket : { bucket_A, bucket_B })
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket_A.size(); ++i)
            if (bucket.shas[i] == sha &&
                Data::slow_equals(bucket.reflinks[i], data))
                return; // duplicate
    auto& smaller_bucket = bucket_A.size() < bucket_B.size()
                           ? bucket_A : bucket_B;
    auto& smaller_sha =    bucket_A.size() < bucket_B.size()
                           ? sha_A : sha_B;
    if (smaller_bucket.size() < max_slots) {
        smaller_bucket.shas.push_back(smaller_sha);
        smaller_bucket.reflinks.push_back(Data::store(data));
        return;
    }
    grow_and_rehash();  // construct a larger hash & copy elements
    insert(data);  // or goto top of fn if you prefer...
}
```

Implementing your own slot mechanism as above to use contiguous memory where possible, and to increase uniformity of collisions at a bucket by using multiple hash values and inserting to the less-collided bucket, will dramatically improve memory utilisation (total memory needed to index all data) and CPU cache hits.